# How to fix SIA10D ROS industrial robot loading model fail in RViz?

Tags: ros, rviz, robot-model, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [ROS-Industrial Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/wiki/Tutorials).

I run:

```
  roslaunch sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch
```

And get partly loaded model of motoman robot.

[image: image description]

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12831/how-to-fix-sia10d-ros-industrial-robot-loading-model-fail-in-rviz?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem you are seeing occurrs when the tf node is not generating the link transforms.  This occurs because this node is probably not started yet.  One reason can be that the warehouse planning configuration has not been accepted (the Rviz window sometimes hides the configuration dialogue when it starts up.

1. Select the planning scene warehouse viewer window (see below)
   [image: image description]
2. Accept the default configuration
   [image: image description]
3. The rest of the application should load correctly.

If this doesn't solve your problem, then you might not have the correct ROS libraries installed.  Please include the roslaunch output if this procedure doesn't work for you.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-02**:
Yes,thank you~ I solve it! I found that I should click accept and "close warehouse_viewer again" to let warehouse_viewer show normal interface and RViz will become normal robot model.